# Focus problems in datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, focus, wpfdatagrid

I am working on an accounting application, My users don't want to touch mouse at all as it will decrease their speed...So focusing is very important in the application.
I am using a datagrid to display some data, what they want is as soon as the window is loaded and data filled in the datagrid they should be able to move around in the data-grid by using arrow keys and invoe a command by pressing Enter...i.e, The keyboard focus should be at the first row or first cell. 
 I have tried almost everything but nothing seems to work here, right now they have to press TAB once to go inside the data-grid even if the the last row is shown as selected in the window I mean last row gets selected but in order to moce up and down in the datagrid they have to press TAB once....I dnot understand what is the problem here...here is the code I am using in loaded event of Windows to set the UI:

```
dataGrid1.SelectedIndex = dataGrid1.Items.Count -1;
dataGrid1.CurrentItem = dataGrid1.SelectedItem;

dataGrid1.Focus();
dataGrid1.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid1.CurrentItem);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `SelectedIndex="0"` for the `DataGrid` and subsribe to the `Loaded` event. In the event handler you move the focus to the first row/cell by calling `MoveFocus`

**Xaml**

```
<DataGrid ...
          SelectedIndex="0"
          Loaded="DataGrid_Loaded">
```

**Code behind event handler**

```
private void DataGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
    dataGrid.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
//set current cell which you want to edit
dataGrid1.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dataGrid1.Items[0], dataGrid1.Columns[0]);
//start editing it
dataGrid1.BeginEdit();
```

I execute this code inside DataGrid's loaded event and works fine

Comment: Thanks mate I was using this before but the problem is it puts that cell in Edit Mode which I don't want as application should behave differently if they hit Enter in that row without typing anything at all.

Comment: what you want then? Cell should be selected without edit mode?

Comment: Exactly what I meant was that the users should be able to move around in the datagrid using up/down keys and issue a certan command by hitting Enter, now the use of command depends upon the current selected item , hence the reason of selecting first row/cell during load..